# CPU seconds value very high on apache mod status even though page is generating very fast

Tags: apache-2.2, cpu-usage

We have a VPS on wich we have a few websites. In the last days it has experience a big load and has sometimes even stoped responding and had to restart it.

After looking into it, we seem to have a high usage of CPU from apache.
We are now looking at the stats from mod_status to find the source.

Below is one example.

What seems to not make sense for us is the high CPU values on some pages.
For example 28.17 on results.42km.ro:80 GET /athletes/view?id=13115 HTTP/1.1

On the explication for columns for CPU it says CPU usage, number of seconds
Does that mean the process took 28 seconds?

```
Current Time: Friday, 15-May-2015 12:49:54 EEST
Restart Time: Friday, 15-May-2015 12:27:35 EEST
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 22 minutes 18 seconds
Server load: 2.09 2.92 2.98
Total accesses: 2556 - Total Traffic: 52.6 MB
CPU Usage: u199.9 s33.2 cu0 cs0 - 17.4% CPU load
1.91 requests/sec - 40.2 kB/second - 21.1 kB/request
2 requests currently being processed, 4 idle workers

.___W.._C.....................

Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process

Srv PID Acc M   CPU     SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
0-0 -   0/0/363 .   19.73   88  0   0.0 0.00    7.11    ::1 vps.server777.ro:443    OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
1-0 16963   0/25/222    _   6.89    2   140 0.0 0.71    4.63    66.249.78.68    results.42km.ro:80  GET /athletes/view?id=14633 HTTP/1.1
2-0 14797   0/213/351   _   28.17   1   113 0.0 3.59    6.25    37.140.141.38   results.42km.ro:80  GET /athletes/view?id=13115 HTTP/1.1
3-0 15585   0/177/305   _   26.38   0   235 0.0 3.33    5.63    82.210.155.128  _wildcard_.galantom.ro:80   GET /tiberiulupu2 HTTP/1.1
4-0 15595   0/184/293   W   27.70   0   0   0.0 7.68    9.08    127.0.0.1   vps.server777.ro:80 GET /whm-server-status/ HTTP/1.0
5-0 -   0/0/82  .   1.47    549 0   0.0 0.00    2.80    ::1 vps.server777.ro:443    OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
6-0 -   0/0/100 .   0.00    566 0   0.0 0.00    1.39    ::1 vps.server777.ro:443    OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
7-0 13690   0/307/307   _   47.44   2   209 0.0 5.97    5.97    109.166.141.79      
8-0 15605   1/166/177   C   28.79   0   260 8.6 3.74    3.82    157.55.39.91    results.42km.ro:80  GET /results/view?id=141538 HTTP/1.1
9-0 -   0/0/7   .   0.00    565 0   0.0 0.00    0.05    ::1 vps.server777.ro:443    OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
10-0    -   0/0/123 .   20.39   560 0   0.0 0.00    1.99    ::1 vps.server777.ro:443    OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
11-0    -   0/0/97  .   3.38    457 0   0.0 0.00    1.71    ::1 vps.server777.ro:443    OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
12-0    -   0/0/129 .   22.76   559 0   0.0 0.00    2.14    ::1 vps.server777.ro:443    OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this when the MySQL server seems to be responding slowly, causing the process to lockup, which burns through the CPU while it waits, so worth taking  a look at your SQL while its struggling to see if that's the real cause.

Comment: Do you know how is the value of CPU time so high even though the page loads in 2-3 seconds?